# Adding a button that open a dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I would like to get some help to add a button that open up a dialog box. Probably it's easy to do, but i didn't manage to implement it so far.

I have the following javascript function:

```
function extract_results(jsonDataRaw){
    jsonResultSect = jsonDataRaw['result']
    retTable = ""
    retText = "ret text <br/>"
    for( key in jsonResultSect){
        myJ = jsonResultSect[key]

        a = myJ['a']
        b = myJ['b']
        c = myJ['c']
        init = myJ['INIT1'] + myJ['INIT2']
        r = myJ['RUNNING']

        retTable += "<tr><td><td>" + key +  "</td><td>" +a + "</td><td>" + b + "</td><td>" + c + "</td><td>" + init + "</td><td>" + r + "</td></tr>"

    }
    return retTable
}
```

In addition, I have the following form:

```
       <div id="contactdiv">
              <form class="form" action="#" id="contact">
                  <img src="images/button_cancel.png" class="img" id="cancel" />
                  <h3>Contact Form</h3>
                  <hr/>
                  <br/>
                  <label>Name: <span>*</span>
                  </label>
                  <br/>
                  <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <label>Email: <span>*</span>
                  </label>
                  <br/>
                  <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <label>Contact No: <span>*</span>
                  </label>
                  <br/>
                  <input type="text" id="contactno" placeholder="10 digit Mobile no." />
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <label>Message:</label>
                  <br/>
                  <textarea id="message" placeholder="Message......."></textarea>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <input type="button" id="send" value="Send" />
                  <input type="button" id="cancel" value="Cancel" />
                  <br/>
              </form>
          </div>
```

I'v took this form from the following [link](http://www.formget.com/jquery-popup-form/).

For each row of `retTable`, i want to add an additional column with a simple button that will popup a dialog box with the above form, and send `key` as a parameter.

Unfortunately, i didn't manage to combine this example in my code. I was able to create a simple popup window that include the form, but i just want the dialog box, and send `key` as parameter.

Comment: semicolons might be optional in some cases in javascript (as long as no 'use strict' is used) but they shouldn't be, include them to keep your code clean, and structured and to avoid unexpected behavior...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My proposed solution displays a div--called popup--which you can, of course, style as a dialogue.  A button has been added to a new column for each row in your data object.  Clicking the button displays the popup, passing in the key index.  Hopefully this is enough to get you going.  My example just passes the key, as you requested, but maybe you want the value instead.  Anyway, hope this helps.

```html
<head>
  <style>
    popup {
      background-color: #eee;
      display: none;
      width: 300px;
      height: 400px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 2px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body onload="start()">
  <div>
    <table id='table'>

    </table>
  </div>
  <popup id='popup'>
    <div id="contactdiv">
      <form class="form" action="#" id="contact">
        <img src="images/button_cancel.png" class="img" id="cancel" />
        <h3>Contact Form</h3>
        <h3 id='the-key'>Key: </h3>
        <hr/>
        <br/>
        <label>Name: <span>*</span>
        </label>
        <br/>
        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <label>Email: <span>*</span>
        </label>
        <br/>
        <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <label>Contact No: <span>*</span>
        </label>
        <br/>
        <input type="text" id="contactno" placeholder="10 digit Mobile no." />
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <label>Message:</label>
        <br/>
        <textarea id="message" placeholder="Message......."></textarea>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input type="button" id="send" value="Send" />
        <input type="button" id="cancel" value="Cancel" />
        <br/>
      </form>
    </div>
  </popup>
</body>

<script>
  function start() {
    var data = {
      'result': [{
        'a': 'a',
        'b': 'b',
        'c': 'c',
        'INIT1': 3,
        'INIT2': 5,
        'RUNNING': 'YES'
      }, {
        'a': 'a',
        'b': 'b',
        'c': 'c',
        'INIT1': 3,
        'INIT2': 5,
        'RUNNING': 'NO'
      }]
    };
    extract_results(data);
  }

  function extract_results(jsonDataRaw) {
    var jsonResultSect = jsonDataRaw['result'];
    var retTable = "";
    var retText = "ret text <br/>";
    for (key in jsonResultSect) {
      var myJ = jsonResultSect[key]

      var a = myJ['a']
      var b = myJ['b']
      var c = myJ['c']
      var init = myJ['INIT1'] + myJ['INIT2']
      var r = myJ['RUNNING']

      table.innerHTML += "<tr><td><td>" + key + "</td><td>" + a + "</td><td>" + b + "</td><td>" + c + "</td><td>" + init + "</td><td>" + r + "</td><td><button onclick='openDialogue(" + key + ")'>Show Key</button></td></tr>"

    }
    return retTable
  }

  function openDialogue(key) {
    document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('the-key').innerHTML = 'Key: ' + key;
  }
</script>
```